# Url trace in Php

Tags: php, curl

I am using get_headers($url,1) to get redirection status. I am getting some results but not for every $url.
If  url1 redirects to url2->ulr3->url4 so on. I want to trace them all.

My code so far:

```
$url = "https://somedomain.com";
$headerarray = get_headers($url,5);

 for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
 {

    if(isset($headerarr1[$i]))
    {
        if(sizeof($headerarr1[$i])>0)
        {
            echo $headerarr1[$i]."->";
            if(isset($headerarr1['Location'][$i]))
            {
                if(sizeof($headerarr1['Location'][$i])>0)
                {
                    echo $headerarr1['Location'][$i]."<br>";
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

I am able to trace if url jumps to 301->302-200ok but this code does not trace all url's. For e.g. If url is not redirecting it should return 200OK. but my code start giving error. Please help me fixing this like undefined Offset 'Location'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get something over and over again until you have your desired result, you probably always need [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). It seems like your code only executes `get_headers` once, so you will only know the first header result and nothing else.

Something like that should do the deal:

```php
$url = 'https://google.com';
$httpCode = '';
while ($httpCode !== 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK') {
    $headers = get_headers($url, 5);

    $httpCode = $headers[0]; // May not be the this key, but you will figure that out yourself.
    if (array_key_exists('Location', $headers) && !empty($headers['Location']) {
        $url = $headers['Location'];
        echo sprintf(' -> %s', $url);
    } else {
        break; // The location header is not set, so we have no idea where to follow to.
    }
}
```

This solution may not be perfect and may require a little bit of trial and error. I can suggest you use some libraries since almost everyone ever had to do some sort of requesting in PHP and there are very good libraries such as [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) out there which makes everything much more simple.

Comment: It is of great help. It only needed minor tweaking to the code and its working fine for me. Thanks a lot